# How to prevent red underline on obj properties

Tags: typescript, tslint

I am having some linter issues with the following code, and I can not understand why since I allow date to be returned as string or null, but it gives red underline when returning a string.

```
static test(): { date: string | null, from: string | null, until: string | null } {

    let returnObj = { 
      date: null, 
      from: null, 
      until: null 
    };

    // Type 'string' is not assignable to type null
    returnObj.date = 'some string';

    return returnObj;
  }
```

IMPORTANT: I do not wish to use @ts-ignore since i have multiple similar assignments, so having a @ts-ignore for every of them makes the code quick ugly.

Thanks!

Comment: "*some linter issues*" – Which rule exactly?

Comment: Hi! Maybe also add your `tslint` file so we'll be able to test this in the same conditions as you? I tried this code with my linter and everything passed with no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using `--noImplicitAny` and `--strictNullChecks`, since that's how I can make that error happen.

The problem is that the inferred type of the properties in `returnObj` is `null`.

You're probably best off creating an interface and using it:

```
interface Stuff {
  date: string | null;
  from: string | null;
  until: string | null;
}

class Example {
  static test(): Stuff {
    let returnObj : Stuff = { 
      date: null, 
      from: null, 
      until: null 
    };

    returnObj.date = 'some string';

    return returnObj;
  }
}
```

Another option is to use individual variables for the values, then create the object at the end:

```
class Example {
  static test(): { date: string | null, from: string | null, until: string | null } {
    let date = null;
    let from = null;
    let until = null;

    date = 'some string';

    return { date, from, until };
  }
}
```

TypeScript is smart enough to update the inferred type of the variable within the function like that. (Or, of course, declare the types on the variables so it doesn't have to infer.)